# how to apply a style to an asp.net menu when the item is selectable=false

Tags: css, asp.net, menu

I'm using the asp.net menu control. Depending on the user's privileges I set some items on the menu to selectable=false. So asp.net takes the link away, cool. But I'd like to make it obviously visually different, e.g. grayed out. i.e. I'd like to have a different CSS style for selectable=true items versus selectable=false items. Is there any way to do this? I don't see an option for it.

Comment: Could you inspect the CSS class for the disabled ones when they render out?  I'm sure there's a rule you can add based on that to differentiate them as you wish.

Comment: Is `selectable` added as an attribute in your menu item? Your question needs more details on how you handle that part and the resulting markup.

Comment: @ricky The asp menu control has a property of "selectable". It doesn't become an attribute of the HTML. Setting selectable to false results in the href not being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply find the links that have no '#' href in css.

```
<style>
        .MenuExample a:not([href='#']) {
            background-color: red !important;
        }
    </style>    
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="3" CssClass="MenuExample">
          <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="File" Value="File">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="New" Value="New"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Open" Value="Open" Selectable="false"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Edit" Value="Edit">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Copy" Value="Copy"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Paste" Value="Paste"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="View" Value="View">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Normal" Value="Normal"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Preview" Value="Preview"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
          </Items>
        </asp:Menu>]
```

Comment: That basically worked. I ended up using ":not([href]) to get both not-a-popup and not-a-link, but yeah.